# Change subview class in subclass

Tags: ios, swift, subclassing

Let's say I have a UITableViewCell class called custom view with a button of class GenericButton, which has been defined in auto layout programmatically

```
class View: UITableViewCell {
    var button: GenericButton

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        button = GenericButton()
        // blah blah blah constraints
    }
}
```

Now let's say I have a subclass of View called OtherView, and I want that button to become a subclass of GenericButton called CircleButton.

```
class OtherView: View {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        button = CircleButton()
    }
}
```

However, my view still shows a GenericButton, not a CircleButton.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've thought about this for several hours and got the conclusion that this is the possibly the best answer.

```
import UIKit

class View: UITableViewCell
{
    var button: GenericButton! = nil

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    convenience init(button: Bool, style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        self.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if button
        {
            button = GenericButton()
            setConstraint()
        }
    }

    private func setConstraint()
    {
        // blah blah blah constraints
    }
}

class OtherView: View
{
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    convenience init(button: Bool, style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        self.init(style: buttonWithStyle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if button
        {
            button = CircleButton()
            setConstraint()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with what my actual code is - how would I go about implementing your solution with a UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: I'm now getting an error in View saying `property 'self.button' not initialized on super.init call` in View's override init(style:, reuseIdentifier:) method.

Comment: Also, if I had a subclass of OtherView, how would I implement that chaining up again - would I have to?

Comment: Would you check my answer?

Comment: I will when I get back to my dorm - thanks for all of your help regardless

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you add button into view hierarchy in `View`. If so, `button = CircleButton()` is meaningless. However, you still can do that way by remove button in `OtherView`, then add it again.

```
class View: UITableViewCell {
    var button: GenericButton

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        button = GenericButton()
        addButton(button)
    }

    func addButton(button: UIButton) {
        // add button into view hierarchy here
    }
}

class OtherView: View {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        button.removeFromSuperview()
        button = CircleButton()
        addButton(button)
    }
}
```